# The Set $x:\left |x+\frac{1}{x}\right|>6=?$

Tags: inequality, roots

The question is that ,the Set $x:\left |x+\frac{1}{x}\right|>6$ equals what intervals of $x$?
My approach:-

I tried to solve the inequality and get interval for $x$'s value as follows:-
$$\left|\frac{x^2+1}{x}\right|-6>0$$
case 1.)
if $x$ is -ive-
$$-x^2-1-6x>0\implies x^2+6x+1<0\implies(x-(-3+2\sqrt2))(x-(-3-2\sqrt2))<0$$so that interval is 
$$(-3-2\sqrt2,-3+2\sqrt2)\tag{1.}$$
case2.)
if $x$ is +ive$$x^2-6x+1>0\implies(x-(3-2\sqrt2))(x-(3+2\sqrt2))>0$$
so that the interval is -:
$$(0,3-2\sqrt2)\cup(3+2\sqrt2,\infty)\tag{2.}$$
The answer would be union of interval (1.) &(2.) but this answer is not in options.

So what is the correct solution of this question? What would be the interval?

Comment: Answer: $x<-3-2\sqrt2$ or $x>3+2\sqrt2$

Comment: Sorry my friend it is not matching with any options ,i have.

Comment: Note that $x^2+1$ is always positive for $x\in\mathbb{R}$ thus $\textrm{sgn}(\frac{x^2+1}{x})=\textrm{sgn}(x)$.

Comment: Careful with case 1, since $x<0$, the direction of the inequality changes when you multiply both sides by $x$.

Comment: Is $(-\infty ,-3-2\sqrt{2})\cup(-3+2\sqrt{2},3-2\sqrt{2})\cup(3+2\sqrt{2},\infty)$ one of the possibilities?

Comment: Right ,so would you please answer the whole solution? Thanx in Advance

Comment: You basically have it right, with only one key problem, your inequality for case 1 is backwards. This is because you didn't change its direction when you multiplied it by $x$, which is negative in that case. Fix that, and you should be able to arrive at the correct solution with what you've done.

Comment: As a side question, is $0$ in that set? If so, or not, why??

Comment: On $0$ set is undefined ,I think.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $$|f(x)|>A \Leftrightarrow$$
$f(x)>A$ or $f(x)<-A$

Or so:

$x>0 \Rightarrow \left(\frac{x^2+1}x-6 \right)>0$

$x<0 \Rightarrow \left(-\frac{x^2+1}x-6 \right)>0$

[image]

Comment: That is what i did as you can see in the question

Comment: case 1) $$\frac{x^2-6x+1}x>0$$

case 2) $$\frac{-x^2-6x-1}x>0$$

Comment: case 1) $$x(x-3+2\sqrt2)(x-3-2\sqrt2)>0$$

Comment: The comment is quite funny because altering the cases doesn't alter the answer ;-)

Comment: Answer: $x<A=-3-2\sqrt2$ or $x>B=3+2\sqrt2$

Comment: Graphical solution confirms my answer

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $$|f(x)|>A \iff f(x)>A \text{  or } f(x) < -A \iff (f(x))^2>A^2$$ when $A$ is positive.

**Details:**

I think this will be an easier method to solve since you don't need to take cases and solve twice. Square the given equation, multiply throughout by $x^2$ and substitute $x^2=t$ to make it a quadratic. Solve the quadratic inequality by factoring the quadratic and then put $t=x^2$ back and solve.

Feel free to comment if you have any problems with this.

Comment: The answer is wonderful but quite time consuming as simplifying the figures will take longer as i have to ultimately match with any one option.

Comment: @MayankDeora If you just want to know which option is correct (assuming there is a correct option), and this is not really a good practice for learning math, just go upto the step where you get the biqaudratic (no need to substitute $x^2$ or solve anything) and put in some values from each of the options to check whether the inequality is satisfied. If it is satisfied by only one option, that is the correct one. Or else, chose more values and check again. Hope this helps!